# Rgraphviz: edge labels outside plotting region

Tags: r, visualization, graphviz, graph-visualization, bioconductor

I am trying to plot a `Rgraphviz` object with two edge labels. Unfortunately the labels fall outside the plot. Here is my example:

```
require('Rgraphviz')
set.seed(123)
g1 <- randomGraph(letters[1:10], 1:4, 0.4)
eAttrs <- list()
eAttrs$label <- c("a~g" = "I have a very long label 1", "a~i" = "and a  long label 2")
plot(g1, edgeAttrs = eAttrs)
```

Here is my plot:

[image]

I tried several things with no success:

**1.**
Set a larger bounding box

```
z <- agopen(g1, "foo")
z@boundBox@upRight@x <- z@boundBox@upRight@x + 300
z@boundBox@upRight@y <- z@boundBox@upRight@y + 300
plot(z, edgeAttrs = eAttrs)
```

**2.**
Decrease the label fontsize (not really what I want in my application, anyways)

```
eAttrs$labelfontsize=c("a~g"="3")
plot(g1, edgeAttrs = eAttrs)
```

**3.**
Change `par` attributes:

```
par(oma=c(10,10,10,10))
plot(g1, edgeAttrs = eAttrs)
```

**4.** 
Change node, edge and general attributes from `?Rgraphviz::GraphvizAttributes`

```
attrs <- list(graph=list(size=c(1, 1)))
attrs$edge$fontsize<-8 
plot(g1, edgeAttrs = eAttrs, attrs=attrs)
```

None of my attempts seem to work. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem

Calling `plot()` on a `graph` object dispatches an S4 method (shown by `getMethod("plot", "graph")`), which in turn calls the function shown by typing `getMethod("plot", "Ragraph")`. That function contains the following rather unfortunate lines which, regardless of any related parameter settings you've made, will override them to reset the left and right margins to 0. Frustrating!

```
oldpars <- par(mai = c(sheight, 0, mheight, 0))
on.exit(par(oldpars), add = TRUE)
```

### A workaround

One workaround is to construct a three panel `layout` in which the left and right panels are just there to provide a bit of buffering space. Turn off clipping, plot your `graph` object in the middle panel, and it then seems to work:

```
layout(matrix(1:3, nrow=1), widths=c(1,5,1))
par(xpd=NA)                    ## turn off all clipping
plot.new()                     ## blank plot in Panel 1
plot(g1, edgeAttrs = eAttrs)   ## graph in Panel 2
plot.new()                     ## blank plot in Panel 3
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, I get an error with `par(mai = c(sheight, 0, mheight, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution: In my original question I changed the size of the bounding box in a laid out graph I got with `agopen`. Plotting the laid out graph showed no edge labels at all. I found that it is possible to pass the edge attributes from the graph object to `agopen` and then change the bounding box:

```
require('Rgraphviz')
set.seed(123)
g1 <- randomGraph(letters[1:10], 1:4, 0.4)
eAttrs <- list()
eAttrs$label <- c("a~g" = "I have a very long label 1", "a~i" = "and a  long label 2")
z <- agopen(g1, "foo", edgeAttr=eAttrs)
z@boundBox@botLeft@x <- z@boundBox@botLeft@x - 400 ##left
z@boundBox@upRight@x <- z@boundBox@upRight@x + 200 ##right
plot(z)
```

The plot:

[image]